# Game center latest score is always best

Tags: xcode, ios7, game-center

In my game I post scores to Game center. The listed high score is always my most recent high score even if it is not better than the actual best score. For example, I post a score of 1000 and look in Game Center and 1000 is my listed best score. After this I post score 100, and this new score of 100 is my listed high score.

Why is it always the last submitted score?

My post score code:

```
 GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:self.leaderboardIdentifier];
 score.shouldSetDefaultLeaderboard = YES;
 score.value = self.overalScore; //self.overalScore is my score after game end 

 [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     if (error != nil) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

In my leaderboard setup:
Score Submission Type:  Most Recent Score
Sort Order:             High to Low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in your leaderboard setup to have it display *most recent score*.

You want it to be *best score* instead. That way every time it will keep it so that the best score will appear for each user.

[image]